# How to deploy an app with a private node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a private library module `mylib` and an app that uses the library `myapp`.
When I deploy `myapp`, I have to include `mylib` in the `node_modules` folder so it gets uploaded as well.
But each time I make changes to `mylib`, I have to go to `myapp` and run `npm install ~/mypath/mylib`, which takes so much time, is there a faster way of dealing with private modules?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use some of CI services. E.g. http://jenkins-ci.org/ .
And you'll be able to set up necessary operations to run on your server after every push to your working git branch (or after private module modification).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a symlink in your application folder to your own lib?

I know this works:

- Have a root folder (f.ex. "application")
- Have a "lib" folder in the root folder
- Have a filesystem link to your private library in that lib folder

The downside is, that you can't access your library without a path, you need to give the path like f.ex. "require('../lib/mylib/xy')", but maybe you find this worth it.